# Enabling/ disabling button base on values of a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, strongloop

I want to display the button only if the user that logs in has the value true for the sendSMS prperty. What should I place in the ng-show in the html to do that? Also I am not too sure if I placed the value for the property correctly. I created a Viewer model with the User as the base model and added a property called sendSMS so that I can use this property to enable/ disable the button.

## create-sample-model.js

```
    var async = require('async');
module.exports = function(app) {
  //data sources
  var db = app.dataSources.db;
  //create all models
  async.parallel({
    viewers: async.apply(createViewers),
  }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  //create reviewers
  function createViewers(cb) {
    db.automigrate('Viewer', function(err) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      var Viewer = app.models.Viewer;
      Viewer.create([
        {email: 'example01@gmail.com', password: 'example123', sendSMS: 'false'},
        {email: 'example02@gmail.com', password: 'User01', sendSMS: 'true'}
      ], cb);
    });
  }
};
```

## auth.js

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('AuthService', ['Viewer', '$q', '$rootScope', function(Viewer, $q,
      $rootScope) {
    function login(email, password, sendSMS) {
      return Viewer
        .login({email: email, password: password, sendSMS: sendSMS})
        .$promise
        .then(function(response) {
          $rootScope.currentUser = {
            id: response.user.id,
            tokenId: response.id,
            email: email
          };
        });
    }
    function logout() {
      return Viewer
       .logout()
       .$promise
       .then(function() {
         $rootScope.currentUser = null;
       });
    }

    function register(email, password, sendSMS) {
      return Viewer
        .create({
         email: email,
         password: password,
         sendSMS: sendSMS
       })
       .$promise;
    }

    return {
      login: login,
      logout: logout,
      register: register
    };
  }]);
```

- This is the auth located in the services folder

auth.js

```
    angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('AuthLoginController', ['$scope', 'AuthService', '$state',
      function($scope, AuthService, $state) {
    $scope.Viewer = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      sendSMS: ''
    };
    $scope.login = function() {
      AuthService.login($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
        .then(function() {
          $state.go('report');
        });
    };
  }])
  .controller('AuthLogoutController', ['$scope', 'AuthService', '$state',
      function($scope, AuthService, $state) {
    AuthService.logout()
      .then(function() {
        $state.go('home');
      });
  }])
    .controller('SignUpController', ['$scope', 'AuthService', '$state',
      function($scope, AuthService, $state) {
    $scope.user = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };

    $scope.register = function() {
      AuthService.register($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
        .then(function() {
          $state.transitionTo('report');
        });
    };
  }]);
```

- This is the auth located in the controllers folder

## report.html

```
<button type="button" ng-show="currentUser.Viewer.sendSMS" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Send sms for selected </button>
```

Comment: Whether you are getting 'currentUser.Viewer.sendSMS' value correctly in report.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-disabled property on the button.
Refer [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) . Button can be disabled based on scope value of sendSMS